# Rfkill refuses to unblock the WiFi device

Tags: linux, usb

Running `rfkill list` indicates the USB WiFi adapter is softblocked. I can run 
`rfkill unblock 0` with no error message, yet running `rfkill list` again indicates the device is still softblocked.

#### Questions

- How can I unblock this device?
- Why is there no warning or error message reporting that it was unsuccessful?

Comment: You need to give more information.  Which distro are you running? Run `lsusb` to get the bus and device number then post the result of `lsusb -v -s bus:devnum` here.